# Running macro with a different number of rows and columns each time

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a tedious task of separating/filtering data and changing the format and making a new sheet.

My question is that if i record a macro for one sheet will it work for another keeping in mind that the number of rows and columns will ALWAYS change.

There's no set number i would have to manually check that if i went into vba and changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Recording is a good way of finding out how to do something, but if you want any kind of fine-grained control over your macro code you'll need to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few ways to get the last row/column in a spreedsheet

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Activesheet.Rows.Count).End(xlup).row
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
```

This will return the last row in column A, you may need to change this depending where your data starts. The `LastCol` will return a number for the column (Note that `.Cells` goes `.Cells([Row Index], [Column Index])`). This is the way I get the last row/column, I find it easier to understand and can do any manipulation needed.

---

```
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
LastColumn = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
```

This is another way to get the last row/column, this does have issues as Excel workouts the last row/column in an odd way. If you edit the last cell in the last row (XFD1048576 in my case) then that becomes the `.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)`s last cell.

Let me know if you need anything clarified

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how do you record it. If you use ctrl+arrows in the recording you may be lucky.
E.g. the following macro works on all rows, simply coloring them in yellow. independent, whether they are 4 or 400:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Makro2()
'
' Makro2 Makro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

It is recorded with CTRL+Arrow, to select the last row.
However, for more complicated code you should not use the recorder.

Answer (score 1):

Recording will give you some basic idea of macro execution. But if you want that code need to work in all scenarios then you need to do some customization to your code.

To find the last row there are so many ways.

Source : http://www.vbausefulcodes.in/usefulcodes/finding-last-row-in-excel-vba.php

```
sub lastrow()
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Msgbox lastrow
End sub


*************************************
Other ways
**************************************

Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

but you need to use the best method which matches with your scenario.